# Calculating Grouped Counts while using Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, sql-server-2012, case

Using SQL Server 2012 - I am trying to accomplish a count of distinct entities from a database, grouped by their Country & Region as well as the type of Company they are. This latter piece is the problem - as there are so many "types", I'm trying to group them into 3 categories: Public, Private and with a catch-all everything else going into 'Other', using a case statement.

The query produces the output I want however I just cannot get the query to group the counts into the categories I've selected. I initially had the CASE statement in the main select query but after finding a similar question elsewhere I moved it to a subquery, but I'm hitting the same issue. Query below with sample output:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ent.factset_entity_id) AS Count, 
    d.[Entity Type], 
    YEAR(r.repr_timeslot_date) AS [Year], 
    cty.country_desc AS Country, 
    reg.region_desc AS Region
FROM
    (SELECT 
         entity_type_code,
         CASE
            WHEN entity_type_code = 'PUB'
               THEN 'Public'
            WHEN entity_type_code IN ('PVT', 'HOL', 'JVT', 'SUB')
               THEN 'Private'
            ELSE 'Other'
         END AS [Entity Type]
     FROM   
         ref_v2.entity_type_map) AS d
JOIN 
    sym_v1.sym_entity AS ent ON ent.entity_type = d.entity_type_code
JOIN 
    sdfdemo.sym_v1.sym_sec_entity AS se ON ent.factset_entity_id = se.factset_entity_id
JOIN 
    repr_v1.repr_factset_id_map AS reprisk ON se.fsym_id = reprisk.factset_id
JOIN 
    repr_v1.repr_rri AS r ON r.repr_company_id = reprisk.provider_id
JOIN 
    ref_v2.country_map AS cty ON cty.iso_country = ent.iso_country
JOIN 
    ref_v2.region_map AS reg ON reg.region_code = cty.region_code
JOIN 
    ref_v2.entity_type_map AS ety ON ety.entity_type_code = ent.entity_type
WHERE  
    reprisk.id_end_date IS NULL
    AND reprisk.factset_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ent.iso_country IN ('SG')
    AND YEAR(r.repr_timeslot_date) = '2020'
    AND r.repr_rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    d.[Entity Type], cty.country_desc, reg.region_desc, 
    ent.entity_type, YEAR(r.repr_timeslot_date);
```

Current output:

| Count | Entity Type | Year | Country | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Other | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 2 | Other | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 12 | Other | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 2 | Other | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 3 | Private | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 455 | Public | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 5 | Private | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |

**Required Output:**

| Count | Entity Type | Year | Country | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | Private | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 455 | Public | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |
| 17 | Other | 2020 | Singapore | Asia |

Greatly appreciate any recommendations!

Comment: FYI: its a case *expression* not statement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `GROUP BY`, you want to group by your calcluated `[Entity Type]` not the one in `sym_v1.sym_entity`.

Change your `GROUP BY` clause to this:

```sql
GROUP BY d.[Entity Type], 
         cty.country_desc, 
         reg.region_desc, 
         YEAR(r.repr_timeslot_date);
```

Here, I've removed `ent.entity_type` from your `GROUP BY` since you don't actually want to group on that, you want to group on your calculated column, which you have already included.

This is what was causing your duplicates.

Comment: thanks, it seems i just didn't spot that repeated line!!